# Ideablade 6.1.16.1 and Cocktail

Tags: devforce

Will their be an update to Cocktail to support 6.1.16.1 soon? Just installed this new version and it seems Cocktail only supports up to 6.1.16.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the 6.1.16.1 release was something of a mixup.  A 6.1.17.0 release will be coming somewhat soon, with corresponding Cocktail support.